# Fragment to fragment to fragment get crash

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a main activity , it contains lots of fragments.
Main activity layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.taiwandigestionsociety_v11.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">


<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
        //switch fragment over here
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and I click the drawer item it will change to first fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
    if (id == R.id.activitiesContents) {
            //change to first fragment successful
            switchFragment(ActivityList.newInstance());
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.activitiesContents);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
```

my switch fragment function:

```
public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment, null);
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

then i click the button in first fragment, it changes to second fragment too:

```
//take me to second fragment succeed
switchFragment(ActivityHomePage.newInstance());
```

finally i click the button in second fragment, it crashed

```
//i want to switch to third fragment , just the same with previous
switchFragment(NewsInformation.newInstance());
```

the error log:
[image: error]

Why i got crash when i switch to third fragment? I completely have no clue.

I found the crash function function , because I set the class:

```
public class CommonSwitch extends Fragment {
    //switch Fragment
    public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment, null);
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

and I try to call it new CommonSwitch.switchFragment(goToFragment);

now I have set public void switchFragment every Fragment class.

Why when I set new CommonSwitch will cause crash ?

Comment: your error log provides no clues where the error occurs!..update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your Activity state is Not Maintain.

On second layer use Activity instead of Fragment . Follow Android Standards.

According to standards Third Fragment should be Activity. otherwise you have to maintain MainActivity state.

Thanks